# Need help optimizing script that hides table rows

Tags: javascript, xpath, optimization, html-table, greasemonkey

I made this Greasemonkey script:

```
var maxpi = 250;
var p1 = "/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[11]";
var p2 = "/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[11]";
..
var p25 = "/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[25]/td[11]";

var r1 = "/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]";
var r2 = "/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]";
..
var r25 = "/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[25]";

var xpathPI1 = document.evaluate(p1, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
..
var xpathPI25 = document.evaluate(p25, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);

var xpathrow1 = document.evaluate(r1, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
..
var xpathrow25 = document.evaluate(r25, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);

if (xpathPI1.singleNodeValue.textContent >maxpi ){
xpathrow1.singleNodeValue.style.display='none';}
..
if (xpathPI25.singleNodeValue.textContent >maxpi ){
xpathrow25.singleNodeValue.style.display='none';}
```

Basically, it checks a table row's 11th field and if its contents > than 250 it hides the row.

With my limited javascript knowledge took quite some time get this working.

The problem is that I have to rewrite every single line if I want to check-hide another row.
I want to make it more usable so I can use it on similar tables without rewriting the whole thing.

Maybe I need to use a different XPath type or use some kind of changing variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop and functions.  Here's one way:

```js
hideRowsWithLargeCellValue (
    "/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[",
    25,
    "]/td[11]",
    250
);

function hideRowsWithLargeCellValue (xpathPre, maxRows, xpathPost, maxpi) {
    for (var J = maxRows;  J >= 1;  --J) {
        var srchRez  = document.evaluate (
            xpathPre + J + xpathPost, 
            document, 
            null, 
            XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, 
            null
        );
        if (srchRez.singleNodeValue  &&  srchRez.singleNodeValue.textContent > maxpi) {
            var rowToHide = srchRez.singleNodeValue.parentNode;
            rowToHide.style.display='none';
        }
    }
}
```

---

---

Then read ["Dont Repeat Yourself"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself) (sic).

Comment: allmost got this working but now problem is that srchRez.singleNodeValue.style.display='none';hides 11th collumn cells if >250 not rows. i want to hide all row if the cell is higher than 250

Comment: Oops!  I slightly misread your code.  See the updated answer.

Comment: cant get it to work.. changed "var rowToHide = xpathrow1.singleNodeValue.parentNode;" to "var rowToHide = srchRez.singleNodeValue.parentNode;" but still nothing, dont know where is the problem

Comment: After your fix, the code should work as well as your old code.  Please link to the target page.  If you can't do that, save a snapshot of the page to http://pastebin.com/ and link to it.

Comment: found why it didnt work. if table contains less than 25 rows it does nothing if it has 25 rows works fine. here is snapshot too http://pastebin.com/9Jcp5rV9

Comment: Sorry about that, I made another rookie mistake.  That's what happens when you don't test. :)  If you look at the error console (Ctrl-Shift-J in Firefox), you'd see both sets of code throwing errors when there were < 25 rows.  I've added the missing check to the answer that fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there are more ways to improve your script.

Firstly, you need to *thoroughly* think through WHAT exactly you want to look for. Is is every row and column? Is it rows/columns with some text, class, any other attribute? You can even select only those nodes that have their text value greater than your `maxpi`!

Read something about **XPath**, the possibly best resource is the [official one](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/).

Some random thoughts on what could be useful regarding XPath:

```
//table//tr[5]/td[2]   ...   the double slash is the deal here
//table//tr/td[number(text()) > 250]   ...   the number() and text() functions
```

---

When talking about **JavaScript**, that would be a little tougher, because there are so many things you could use!

Just for starters - you can create dynamically changing xpath expressions by [String concatenation](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+String+concatenation) and [For loop](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20for%20loop), like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= maxNumberOfRows; i++) {
    var p1 = "//table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]";
    // more work goes here...
}
```

Also, you could use [arrays](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20array) to store multiple nodes returned by your XPath expressions and work on them all with just a single command.

For more JavaScript, I would recommend the first chapters of some [JavaScript tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript), that will boost your productivity by a lot.